# Create multiply amount of files with random names in python and zip them

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm newbie in Python,

I need to create a large quantity of files with random names in `Dest_Dir` (my destination directory), And then Zip them to one file.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?
I managed to create files like that with a `for` loop into a specific folder, but it doesn't fit in case I want to create large amount of file (Lets say 100)
And the names I created aren't random.

```
import os
import sys
import platform
SRC_Dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
Dest_Dir = os.path.join(SRC_Dir, 'dest')
items = ["one", "two", "three"]
for item in items:
    #(os.path.join(Dest_Dir, filename), 'wb') as temp_file:
    with open(os.path.join(Dest_Dir, item), 'wb') as f:
        f.write("This is my first line of code")
        f.write("\nThis is my second line of code with {} the first item in my list".format(item))
        f.write("\nAnd this is my last line of code")
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of your code attempt please?

Comment: You should first read about [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) and [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) modules.

Comment: he probably meant   fit    not feet, deduce.....

Comment: Is that more understandable?

Comment: You already have an iterable in `items = ["one", "two", "three"]`, now just replace that with the type of random file name that you want using the tools in the `random` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of the built-in `tempfile`

```
import os
import tempfile

for _ in range(100):
    file_descriptor, file_path = tempfile.mkstemp(".txt", "prefix-", Dest_Dir)
    file_handle = open(file_path, "wb")
    # do stuff
    os.close(file_descriptor)
    file_handle.close()
```

Since a comment was made about the zip part I figured I would add that as well

```
import os
import tempfile
import zipfile

new_files = []
for _ in range(10):
    file_descriptor, file_path = tempfile.mkstemp(".txt", "prefix-", "/tmp")
    file_handle = open(file_path, "wb")
    file_handle.write("HELLO")
    os.close(file_descriptor)
    file_handle.close()
    new_files.append(file_path)

with zipfile.ZipFile("/tmp/zipped.zip", "w") as zipped:
    for file_path in new_files:
        zipped.write(file_path, os.path.basename(file_path))
```

The `zipped.write` arguments here assume only the filename (and not the path) are desired for the archived name.